# CSharp : extracting variable from one loop to another

Tags: loops, variables, while-loop

Im having an issue with setting up a calculator.
The variable(method) is a char and its being input on the first while loop.
on the second while loop i want the variable(method) from the first loop tobe transfered into the second loop.
but there is an error and it says that the variable is unassigined.
please help.
here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int continu = 0;
        int continu2 = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To The Alpha Calculator!");
        Console.WriteLine("First,Type A Method");
        char method;
        while (continu2 != 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Type '+' or '-' or '*' or '/' :");
            method = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (method == '+' || method == '/' || method == '*' || method == '-')
            {
                continu = 1;
                continu2 = 1;
                Console.WriteLine(method + " Picked");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown Method Try Again");


            }
            char method2 = method;
        }


        while (continu != 0)
        {

            Console.Write("Pick A First Digit:");
            double num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Pick A Second Digit:");
            double num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double sum = 0;
          if (method == '+')
            {
                sum = num1 + num2;
            }
            else if (method == '-')
            {
                sum = num1 - num2;
            }
            else if (method == '/')
            {
                sum = num1 / num2;
            }
            else if (method == '*')
            {
                sum = num1 * num2;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The Solution is: " + sum);
            continu = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're actually doing it correctly with the variable `method`. Look at the error you're getting - "the variable is unassigned". This makes sense, because you declared it without defining it. But it's supposed to get defined within that first loop, so why isn't it defined when it gets to the second loop?

The answer is that the first loop *isn't even running*. The problem is these two lines:

```
int continu2 = 0;
...
while (continu2 != 0)
{
    ...
}
```

You see, the condition `continu2 != 0` is false from the start, so the loop - including the line inside it `method = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` that would get rid of your error - never runs at all.

The solution: change your condition to `continu2 == 0` instead of `continu2 != 0`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but thats not the problem.
the variable continu is 1 when if statement gets true.
i tried anyway to check your code but it isnt working...
the variable that unassigned is method